# Unpassive change in RestSharp 106.6.2

Tags: restsharp, defects

.net Core. 
Using RestSharp 106.5.4, this was valid. The Priorities endpoint supports a `List<string> priorities` as a query parameter.

```
string server = "http://localhost:11111";
var client = new RestClient(server);
string filter = "?priority=Low&priority=Medium"
var request = new RestRequest($"priorities{filter}", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<Priorities>(request);
```

When I view the response objects ResponseUri property, it has 
http://localhost:11111/priorities**?priority=Low&priority=Medium**

Exactly like I would expect.  I upgraded my project to use RestSharp 106.6.2, and the request URI completely changed, and breaks existing code.

With RestSharp 106.6.2, it changes my URI and I get this ResponseUri back

http://localhost:11111/priorities?**priority=Low,Medium**

This means I now only get one element in my array of string in the request, comma seperated, instead of 2 elements like it did before.

Why was this unpassive change made?  This broke our clients because now it only sees one element passed into the list of priorities, and that is *"Low,Medium"*, instead of the two elements in the array as it should.  This changes what was passed into the call, and makes the call invalid as Low,Medium is not a value, Low is a value, and Medium is a value.

Is this a defect in restsharps newest version, or was this done on purpose?

I know I can turn and use the parameters objects to do this, but up until the newest restsharp version, I didn't have too and it worked perfectly.